# Cloudflare giving JavaScript challanges / captcha on javascript files?

Tags: cloudflare, captcha, firewall

I'm trying to set up Cloudflare properly for my site. Most things seem to work properly, but when I tried to load the page in Tor, I ran into a problem. The HTML loaded properly, but when Tor tried to load a script referenced in the document, Cloudflare gave a captcha on the JavaScript file:

[image: Tor showing a Captcha on a JavaScript file]

As the browser tried to load a JavaScript file and instead got some HTML, the script obviously didn't load. The Firewall section on Cloudflare also confirms this:

[image: Cloudflare firewall showing the page was blocked]

What would be the correct way of solving this? Disabling the firewall on any non-html file seems like it would open the site to many kinds of attacks, but letting the firewall block any non-html files will obviously not work, as it leads to these kinds of situations.

(It seems to me like something is fundamentally wrong with this kind of setup. If you block access to certain files only to make attacking the site harder, then the attacker should just be able to perform the attack on any non-protected files. Do I fundamentally misunderstand something here?)

Answer (score 1):

Go into your Cloudflare dashboard and check you're Under Attack mode.  If it is on, turn it off. You should also check your page rules

Comment: Nope, Under Attack mode has always been off

Comment: Do you have any firewall or page settings?

Comment: I haven't changed the firewall settings or page settings in any way

Comment: @NathanielSturtz - Not sure if English is your first language or not, but this answer is really hard to read and doesn't make sense.  Are you able to clarify the part after "Under Attack"?

Comment: @Steve sorry, it was late @ night and I was tried, English is my first language let me reface it if under attack mode is off do nothing if it is on then turn it off

Comment: @NathanielSturtz - oops, I misread your comment.  Thanks for fixing up my edit.

Comment: @Steve No problem,